# Using PendingIntent in Android

Tags: android, android-pendingintent, foreground-service

My app worked fine with older Android, but got exception when try to run it on Android 34

Code:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,    0, notificationIntent, 0);
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.kpv.mqtt: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
                                                                                                Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
```

Changed to code with flag :

New code:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,    0, notificationIntent, FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
```

Got exception:

```
 Unable to start service com.xxx with Intent { cmp=com.xxx.mqtt/.MqttGndService (has extras) }: android.app.MissingForegroundServiceTypeException: Starting FGS without a type  callerApp=ProcessRecord{cd4e08b 9230:com.xxx.mqtt/u0a182} targetSDK=34
```

How to solve this problem?

UPD

I have added android:foregroundServiceType="dataSync" to service in manifest:

```
    <service
        android:name=".MqttGndService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:foregroundServiceType="dataSync"
        android:exported="false"></service>
```

After this change I got exception:

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.kpv.mqtt, PID: 5592
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.kpv.mqtt.MqttGndService@c53fa9b with Intent { cmp=com.kpv.mqtt/.MqttGndService (has extras) }: java.lang.SecurityException: Starting FGS with type dataSync callerApp=ProcessRecord{34f694e 5592:com.kpv.mqtt/u0a182} targetSDK=34 requires permissions: all of the permissions allOf=true [android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_DATA_SYNC] 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:4839)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleServiceArgs(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2289)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Starting FGS with type dataSync callerApp=ProcessRecord{34f694e 5592:com.kpv.mqtt/u0a182} targetSDK=34 requires permissions: all of the permissions allOf=true [android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_DATA_SYNC] 
    at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:3057)
    at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:3041)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:3024)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2966)
    at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.setServiceForeground(IActivityManager.java:6761)
    at android.app.Service.startForeground(Service.java:775)
    at com.kpv.mqtt.MqttGndService.onStartCommand(MqttGndService.java:470)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:4821)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleServiceArgs(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2289) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971) 
Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
    at com.android.server.am.ActiveServices.validateForegroundServiceType(ActiveServices.java:2611)
    at com.android.server.am.ActiveServices.setServiceForegroundInnerLocked(ActiveServices.java:2322)
    at com.android.server.am.ActiveServices.setServiceForegroundLocked(ActiveServices.java:1679)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.setServiceForeground(ActivityManagerService.java:13265)
    at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:3385)
```

Comment: Please edit your question and past the stacktrace from the exception. Also paste the `<service>` declaration from your manifest into the question. It looks like you are trying to start a foreground `Service` without having specified the foreground service type in your manifest. See https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/changes/fgs-types-required

Comment: I have added `android:foregroundServiceType="dataSync"` to `service` and got exception. More details in question body

Comment: If you read the stacktrace, it tells you the reason for the exception: **"kpv.mqtt/u0a182} targetSDK=34 requires permissions: all of the permissions allOf=true [android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_DATA_SYNC]"**. You need to add this permission to your manifest.

Answer (score 1):

Add an Immutable flag in your pending intent, and you can separate condition for android 12 like this

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,    0, notificationIntent,  PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT || PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
 }
 else {
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,    0, notificationIntent,  PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT );
 }
```

same with mutable intent you can change only flags like **PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE**

and this type exception ( Unable to start service com.xxx with Intent) occurs when
you can not declare in your foreground service type
refer to this link for more understanding

1. https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services
2. https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/changes/fgs-types-required

service type required on Android 12 or greater version.you can add in your manifest like this and add the necessary permission

```
<service
      android:name=".MyMediaPlaybackService"
      android:foregroundServiceType="mediaPlayback"
      android:exported="false">
  </service>
```

Comment: But `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT || PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE` brings `bad operand types for binary operator '||'first type:  int second type: int `